# Insert data in database when line change in textarea using php or javascript. without any click or any submit buttons

Tags: php, database, insert

I have a TextArea. i want when i write data in textarea and when line change in textarea then data is insert in table and textarea is blank automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery. Choose one method. **DO NO USE** both methods.

Submit via Form - It will refresh the page

```
<script>
    $("#textarea-id").keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            $('#form-id').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Submit via Ajax - it will not refresh the page

```
<script>
    $("#textarea-id").keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insertrecords.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: 'name=paul',
                success: function (data) {
                    //called when successful
                    $('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    //console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```